# Maximizing edges in directed acyclic graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, asymptotics, extremal-graph-theory

**Question:** What is the maximum number of edges in a non-transitive [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) on $n$ vertices?

Here nontransitive means, if there is an edge between $A$ and $B$, and an edge between $B$ and $C$, then there *cannot* be an edge between $A$ and $C$.

For example, see the following image:
[image]

**Easier(?) question:** What is the [asymptotic behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_behavior) of the maximum number of edges in the limit as the number of vertices $n \rightarrow \infty$? Eg., $\#\mathrm{edges}=O(?)$.

**Comment:** Someone else asked this question in the computer science stack exchange, but the question got deleted. The question piqued my curiosity but I can't figure it out, which is why I'm reposting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $\lfloor\frac{n^2}4\rfloor$.

First, your graph can't have any triangles; neither of the two ways to orient a triangle satisfies your requirements.

By [Turán's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem), or rather the special case known as [Mantel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem#Mantel.27s_theorem), a triangle-free (simple) graph on $n$ vertices has at most $\lfloor\frac{n^2}4\rfloor$ edges. The maximum is attained by the complete bipartite graph $K_{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor,\lceil\frac n2\rceil}$. If all the edges are directed from one partite set to the other, there are no cycles and everything is fine.

Comment: Ahh perfect! I was thinking about the directed bipartite graph as well, but doubted it's optimality.