Given $n$ equivalent statements. What is the most amount of implications one can use to prove that all statements are equivalent?
I found this question interesting but have no idea how to go about it. I suspect one can use some advanced graph theory, but I am not particularly strong in that area. Here is the question:
Given $n$ equivalent statements $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$, what is the highest number of implications $A_i \implies A_j$, $i \neq j$ one can use in order to prove that all statements are equivalent. No implication can be a direct consequence of the previous ones, i.e. if $A_1 \implies A_2$ and $A_2 \implies A_3$ are already proven, $A_1 \implies A_3$ does not count towards the total number of implications used.

This is equivalent to the problem under the following link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660123/maximizing-edges-in-directed-acyclic-graph

I am not sure if get why the two problems are equivalent.. I do not require the graph to be acyclic. If $A_1 \implies A_2$ and $A_2 \implies A_3$ then $A_3 \implies A_1$ does not follow immediately from the two previous ones.

Is the word "previous" load-bearing? For example, can we include $A_1 \implies A_2$ and $A_1 \implies A_3$, and then later include $A_2 \implies A_3$ and count all three?

Indeed, the example you provided would be valid

I see that I misinterpreted the question, I will delete my answer. @MishaLavrov nice catch!

We will prove by induction that for all $n\ge 1$, after $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - 1$ implications are proved, all of $A_1, \dots, A_n$ are equivalent. This is true for $n=1$, since $A_1$ is equivalent to itself after $0$ implications are proved.
Now assume this upper bound is true for all $k < n$. In particular, this assumption implies that for any subset $\mathcal S \subseteq \{A_1, \dots, A_n\}$ of size $k$, at most $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}-1$ implications can ever be proved between two elements of $\mathcal S$. (After this many implications between elements of $\mathcal S$ are proved, all elements of $\mathcal S$ are known to be equivalent even if nothing else is known, and no more implications between elements of $\mathcal S$ can be proved.)
Consider any sequence of implications between $A_1, \dots, A_n$ which never proves anything implied by previous steps, and after which all of these elements are known to be equivalent. Let's assume that $A_i \implies A_j$ was the last implication to be proved, and look at our state of knowledge right before this implication. Let $\mathcal S \subseteq \{A_1, \dots, A_n\}$ be the set of all statements known to follow from $A_i$. Let $\mathcal T$ be the complement of $\mathcal S$. Neither $\mathcal S$ nor $\mathcal T$ are empty, since $A_i \in \mathcal S$ and $A_j \in \mathcal T$.
By induction, we have proved at most $\frac{|\mathcal S|(|\mathcal S|+1)}{2}-1$ implications within $\mathcal S$ and at most $\frac{|\mathcal T|(|\mathcal T|+1)}{2}-1$ implications within $\mathcal T$. Also, we could not have proved any implications from $\mathcal S$ to $\mathcal T$, because anything that follows from a statement in $\mathcal S$ is also in $\mathcal S$, so we have proved at most $|\mathcal S| \cdot |\mathcal T|$ implications between the two sets: the ones from $\mathcal T$ to $\mathcal S$. Remember, this is all counted before $A_i \implies A_j$ is proved.
Adding in our last statement, we see that the maximum number of implications in our sequence is
$$
    \left(\frac{|\mathcal S|(|\mathcal S|+1)}{2}-1\right) + \left(\frac{|\mathcal T|(|\mathcal T|+1)}{2}-1\right) + |\mathcal S| \cdot |\mathcal T| + 1
$$
which simplifies to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - 1$: and that was what we wanted.

This proof also leads us to many different equally good extremal constructions that achieve the bound of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1$. Pick any partition $\mathcal S \cup \mathcal T$ of $\{A_1, \dots, A_n\}$. If we first prove all implications from $\mathcal T$ to $\mathcal S$, then handle each of $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal T$ using as many implications as possible, and then finally prove any one implication from $\mathcal S$ to $\mathcal T$, we will achieve this bound. (The only thing we have to be careful to do is proving all the implications from $\mathcal T$ to $\mathcal S$ first, since they might otherwise be deduced from later steps.)

I attempted the following greedy algorithm:
We construct out-edges from each $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n$ sequentially. For each $i = 1, 2, \cdots, n - 1$. Note that $A_i \implies A_{i + 1}$ has not been proved yet, so we can prove $A_i \implies A_{i + 1}$. Since $A_{i + 1} \implies A_{i + 2}$ has also not been proved, we can prove $A_i \implies A_{i + 2}$ as well. Continue this way, we can prove all $A_i \implies A_{i + j}$ for $j = 1, 2, \cdots, n - i$. There is also no proved implication $A_i \implies A_{i - 1}$ if $i \geq 2$, so we can prove that as well. However, the moment when we try to prove $A_i \implies A_k$ for some $k < i - 1$, a problem occurs because $A_{i - 1} \implies A_{i - 2} \implies \cdots \implies A_1$ would have been proved in previous iterations, and so $A_i \implies A_k$ is already automatic since $A_1 \implies A_k$ has been established previously. Therefore, for $A_1$ we can prove $(n - 1)$ statements and for every $A_i$ with $2 \leq i \leq n - 1$, we can prove $(n - i + 1)$ statement, which makes a total of $\left(\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} - 1\right)$ provable statements.
I believe this algorithm should be correct, but am stuck at proving the optimality of the algorithm. Any help or inspiration is appreciated.

Edit: This response solves the wrong problem (not considering order). I will leave it for context.
This problem is equivalent to "what is the largest number of edges in an edge-critical strongly connected digraph on $n$ vertices?", i.e. a strongly connected directed graph where the removal of any edge makes the graph not strongly connected. This paper provides a citation that the answer is $2(n-1)$, but it's not so hard to prove by induction on $n$.
The case $n=1$ is trivial. For the inductive case, suppose $n\geq 2$ and $D=(V,E)$ has at least one edge $e$. Consider the strongly connected components of $D-e$, call them $C_1,\ldots,C_k$. By induction each component $C_i$ has at most $2(|C_i|-1)$ edges and we can see there are at most $k-1$ edges joining these components (why?). Adding these up (plus $e$) we get at most $2n-k\leq 2n-2$ edges in total.
Note: Ronno gave an example where $2n-2$ suffices (a path graph with edges in both directions). Actually any tree with bidirectional edges suffices.

The two problems are not equivalent; this answer and Ronno's do not consider the order in which edges are added. If $G$ is the final digraph and $e = (u,v)$ is an edge, it is possible that $G-e$ is still strongly connected, if some edges of the $u \to v$ path in $G-e$ were added after $e$. In the language of the question: no implication can be a consequence of the previous ones, but there is no requirement that no implication can be a consequence of any other ones.

@MishaLavrov Thanks I see now why others got different answers. So redundancy is allowed, as long as each new implication proves something new.
